# Where do I find previous Tor consensuses, and other metrics data?

Tags: directory, consensus

i am looking to do a bit of research on previous Tor consensuses, i am looking to go back years, is there a location that saves every previous consensus ?

Thanks Rich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out: https://collector.torproject.org/archive/relay-descriptors/consensuses/ and the main page (https://collector.torproject.org/) for more info.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i am looking for thanks ! :)